# "type" rather than "list-style-type" in HTML

Tags: html, types, html-lists

Can I use only "type" attribute rather than list-style-type for ul and ol? (disc, square etc.)

If so, why there is two options? Thanks

Comment: `list-style` is just a shortened version of `list-style-type`.

Comment: I think they are trying to compare the (nonexistent?) property `type` and `list-style-type`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

CSS property is called `list-style-type`, you can shortened to `list-style`. `type` is unknown and invalid property.

And there are more options than just `disc/square`, full list see at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/#values-for-list-style-type